# Is there any way to get the value without using the loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Id       DependentId
-----    ------------
2        5
5        8
8        6
6        7
7        NULL
3        10
10       15
17       NULL
15       NULL
```

I wrote a function that return 7 from above table if we pass the parameter 2.

Other examples: return value is 15 if parameter value is 3.

Return value will be 17 if input parameter is 17

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getValue
(
 @Id INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DependentId AS INT
    WHILE (1 = 1)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @DependentId = DependentId FROM dbo.givenTable WHERE  Id = @Id;
            IF (@DependentId IS NOT NULL)
                    SET @Id = @DependentId
            ELSE
                BREAK;
        END 
        RETURN @Id
END
GO
```

Is there any way to get the value without using the loop?

Comment: mysql <> sql server, please don't tag products not involved

Comment: Also, don't use images for data/code, use formatted text. I rolled your image-edit back (or maybe Zohar beat me to it).

Comment: For SQL Server, use a recursive CTE. For MySql I don't know.

Comment: If you need a query, why don't you go and write one then? We're not here to do your work for you. If you have a question, or are struggling and can show what you've already tried, however, then we're happy to help you.

Comment: how can id=2 give you two different results? 7 and 15 in your example are both for id=2

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loop you can use [Recursive CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/). Termination logic for CTE is `WHERE DependentID is NULL`.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getValue
    (
        @Id INT
    )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @result INT;
        WITH RecursiveCTE
        AS ( SELECT ID ,
                    dependentID ,
                    Id AS BaseDependentId
             FROM   givenTable 
             WHERE  dependentID IS NULL

             UNION ALL

             SELECT T.id ,
                    T.DependentId ,
                    cte.BaseDependentId
             FROM   givenTable  AS T
                    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE cte ON T.DependentId = cte.id
             )
        SELECT @result = BaseDependentId
        FROM   RecursiveCTE
        WHERE  Id = @Id

        RETURN @result

    END
GO
```